# How to insert a function output into an array for another function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code as part of an idea to teach my kid how to read time. I'm trying to take the output of the clock program and insert it into a list of incorrect times. The idea being when the correct time, in comparison to an analogue clock, shows to then say so.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    .clock {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      font-size: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onLoad="startclock()">
  <div id="changeTime" class="clock"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var timerID = null
    var timerRunning = false

    function stopclock() {
      if (timerRunning)
        clearTimeout(timerID)
      timerRunning = false
    }

    function startclock() {
      stopclock()
      showtime()
    }

    function showtime() {
      var now = new Date()
      var hours = now.getHours()
      var minutes = now.getMinutes()
      var timeValue = "" + ((hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours)
      timeValue += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes
      timeValue += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M."
      document.getElementsByClassName("clock").value = timeValue
      timerID = setTimeout("showtime()", 1000)
      timerRunning = true
    }

    var myTime = ['08:07 A.M.', '10:15 A.M.', '03:43 P.M.', '07:44 P.M.', '11:59 A.M.', '01:19 P.M.', '01:21 A.M.'];
    myTime.push(timerID);
    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeTime");
    setInterval(change, 3000);

    function change() {
      var counter = Math.floor(Math.random() * myTime.length);
      elem.innerHTML = myTime[counter];
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried using what I think is the correct variable and using push to insert it into the list however when the correct time is supposed to show it goes blank. My other problem is that when initially activated the first three seconds it is always blank. Any help fixing these two issues would be gratefully appreciated as I'm still very much learning javascript.

Please check [www.testing12audio.com](http://www.testing12audio.com) for what I have so far.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following what you're trying to achieve. Can you make a JS Fiddle or simplify your question a little bit more?

Comment: Hi. Certainly, not a problem. The first part of the above code down to the line timeRunning = true is a standard clock showing hours and minutes as well as AM or PM. From there down is a program randomly putting out a value from the var myTime. what I'm trying to do is take the output of the clock and insert it into the var myTime as one of the list that can be randomly selected.

Comment: document.clock.face.value = timeValue

This line throws JS error. Please keep the code simple and run-able....@Skinner

Comment: The code works for the clock, as does the random output from the list. I've run both seperately with no problems

Comment: You can now see what I have so far at www.testing12audio.com

Comment: the value for timerID is always null. When I assigned the  var timerID = setTimeout("showtime()", 1000) I see the number appear on the list. also try calling the clock  using this code      document.getElementsByClassName("clock").value = timeValue

Comment: Hi Jose, can you elaborate on the code you are talking about. If I swap out the var timerID = null with what you suggest I get the number 1 appear at the point when the correct time should not the actual time. Explain a bit more please

Comment: Please repair the code snippet, doesn't work.

Comment: Repaired the code snippet thanks to Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 problems:

- Things were getting blank
- Non-functional for the first 3 seconds

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
    .clock {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      font-size: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onLoad="startclock()">
  <div id="changeTime" class="clock"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var timerID = null
    var timerRunning = false

    function stopclock() {
      if (timerRunning)
        clearTimeout(timerID)
      timerRunning = false
    }

    function startclock() {
      stopclock()
      showtime()
    }
    var myTime = ['08:07 A.M.', '10:15 A.M.', '03:43 P.M.', '07:44 P.M.', '11:59 A.M.', '01:19 P.M.', '01:21 A.M.'],
      timeVal;

    function showtime() {
      var now = new Date()
      var hours = now.getHours()
      var minutes = now.getMinutes()
      var timeValue = "" + ((hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours)
      timeValue += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes
      timeValue += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
      timerID = setTimeout(showtime, 1000);
      if (timeValue != timeVal) {
        if (timeVal !== undefined) {
          myTime.pop();
        }
        myTime.push(timeValue);
        timeVal = timeValue;
      }
      timerRunning = true
    }

    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeTime");

    (function change() {
      var counter = Math.floor(Math.random() * myTime.length),
        time = myTime[counter];
      elem.innerHTML = myTime[counter];
      if (time === timeVal) {
        // if displayed the correct time, its pushed out of the array.
        myTime.pop();
        timeVal = undefined;
      }
      setTimeout(change, 1500);
    })();
  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: @skinner This isnt the exact solution. Help me understanding the problem in this solution. We aint getting you in a clarified way. showtime () needs improvement.

Comment: @skinner Please validate whats missing.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to take the output of the clock ( function showtime() I think) and insert it into the var myTime so that it shows up as one of the random times on the screen

Comment: Hey @Skinner, I think I get you. So initially you have a myTime array containing some time list. I have made some modifications. Now after every 1 min. time there is a new time appended to the array. Have given console logs for additions too.

So keep this program running for a couple of hours and it has whole lot of bunch of random time for the kid to learn!

Lemme know if I am still missing something here brother.

Comment: Hi, yeah, basically I want to put the correct time in amongst a bunch of wrong times to flash up individually on the screen so that when the correct time shows he then has to say so. I don't want the list to get too big as I don't want him to have to wait 10 minutes for the correct time to appear though. Appreciate your help

Comment: Hi Ayan, what you've done is great but what I would ask is that if possible to do it with out logging the previous minutes with the console logs. They might be a bit to close to the actual time for a little kid if only out by a minute or so to figure out that they are wrong. Thanks buddy

Comment: Hey @Skinner Have solved the issue of long array length. Now the array has 7 wrong time entries, and 1 correct time. The screen flashes a time after every 1.5 secs. After every 1 minute the correct time is updated. So at no instant the array length becomes more than 8, and the child has to wait long for the correct time.

Have updated, Lets check now. Calls for an upvote or acceptance if you would love this :-) . A well thought problem.